# KIF tapping on UIAlertView in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, automated-tests, kif-framework

Hello folks,

I have a strange issue and hope someone can give me a hint...

I test the UI of my app with the `KIF-Framework`. On a specific situation I get an `UIAlertView` with three buttons. Before I tap on one of these buttons I check if all of these are visible with the method `stepToWaitForTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel` after that I tap a button with `stepToTapViewWithAccessibilityLabel`.

This working fine if the app is in the portrait view, but if I test the same in landscape the  tapping on the `UIAlertView` won't work although **KIF** tells me the tapping was successful. All steps passed but the `UIAlertView` wouldn't be dismissed, and therefore my following steps fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue on the GitHub page: https://github.com/square/KIF/issues/60

This solution is not in the current repo but fix my problem!